# What is French equivalent to the English word "as"?

Tags: grammaire, usage, prépositions

I am trying to figure out how to say "I am one of the first people in my family to have English as my mother tongue." Currently, I have "Je suis l’un des premières personnes dans ma famille avoir Anglais". I know that mother tongue is "langue maternelle". But, I've been going back and forth as to how to express the English word "as". I was considering using "est". But, I thought that would be incorrect because "est" translates to "is" and not "as". Any enlightenment on the subject would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/as), the various possibilities are present in the examples. *As* is a preposition in you sentence. And also:   "...to have English.."  will be ***à** avoir **l**'anglais*

Answer (score 7):

How about:

> Je suis un des premiers dans ma famille dont la langue maternelle est l'anglais.

Or:

> Je suis parmi les premiers de ma famille dont la langue maternelle est l'anglais.

Comment: I'd have left out the "people/persons" in English, so +1 for doing so in French! Also, if you don't mind answering, I notice that you also omit the "l'" before "un," unlike the other answers so far that keep it (before "une" in those cases). Is including it or not just a matter of style or does it have something to do with the gender of the indefinite article (genre: "l' before une but not before un")? Thanks!

Comment: @PapaPoule     You might find the following page useful. http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/unlun.htm

Comment: @PapaPoule the **l'** is entirely optional,  whether orally or in writing, Grevisse does not even mention a difference in register.

Comment: @Laure Am I right in thinking that substituting "l'un/l'une" for "un/une" is for, among other things, facilitating pronunciation, just like "l'on" vs "on"? I make it a rule to use "l'un/l'une" when I want to add emphasis on it. Merci.

Comment: @LUNA I'm not personally convinced by the euphonic aspect of this use of the **l'**  although I know it is sometimes mentioned. Just like some mention a difference in register (that's why I mentioned earlier Grevisse says nothing about register).

Comment: "*parmi*" with "*dont*" sounds wrong to me but I couldn't explain why. I think it's because there is no definite or indefinite article ("***un** des premiers*"), but I don't know if my feeling is right.

Answer (score 5):

**As** is corresponding here to ***comme*** or ***pour***. A word by word translation might give:

> Je suis l'une des premières personnes de ma famille à avoir l'anglais **comme** langue maternelle.
>
> Je suis l'une des premières personnes de ma famille à avoir l'anglais **pour** langue maternelle.
>
> Je suis l'un des premiers de ma famille ayant l'anglais **comme** langue maternelle.

Note that I kept the original sentence structure as close as possible in order to properly answer to your question. The remaining answers so far are all rephrasing the sentence in a way that avoid the need to translate "as".

Comment: To: jlliagre On the other hand, « parler l'anglais **comme** ma langue maternelle » means "speak English {**like / as well as**} my first language", correct? I find it interesting to see these two « comme »s used in a similar way but with a completely different meaning. Merci.

Comment: @Luna: FWIW that ambiguity exists in English. "I speak English as my first language" could be interpreted as an elision, "I speak English [the same] as my first language" or equivalently "I speak English as [I speak] my first language". It's just that if you use "as" like that in English you sound like you're in a Jane Austen novel.

Comment: This is because you can't tell other than from context and expectation, whether "as" in the sentence "I speak English as my first language" is a preposition applying to "my first language", in which case it means English has the role "my first language", or an adverb applying to "speak" and meaning "identically with".

Comment: @LUNA *avoir* and *parler* are significantly different, I wouldn't say *comme* is used a similar way in your example and my word by word translation.

Comment: @LUNA I believe it more accurate to say that *avoir X comme Y* is a special construction. Unless I'm mistaken, it's a variant of *avoir X pour Y*, which has the same meaning, with a different preposition.

Comment: I don't like this phrasing. It doesn't seem idiomatic to me.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I agree it is not the best translation, but the OP doesn't ask for an idiomatic translation, he asks for an equivalent to "as". That's the reason why I kept the sentence structure unchanged and proposed a word by word translation.

Comment: "Comme" is a very good translation for "as". Sure, a French would have said the sentence differently but using "comme" as a translation for "as" is perfectly correct. "en tant que" can also be used, in different contexts.

Answer (score -3):

Je suis l’une des premières personnes dans ma famille dont l'Anglais est ma langue maternelle.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Fred. Your sentance sound a little strange to me, though. I would say "la langue maternelle" rather than "ma" and "de ma famille" instead of "dans ma famille".

Answer (score -4):

Je suis le première personne dans ma famille ayant l'Anglais comme langue maternelle.

google translate has:

Je suis la première personne dans ma famille d'avoir l'anglais comme langue maternelle.

Comment: Welcome to French Language guest12345. Don't trust google translate, it's rarely good. And no French native would say this.

Comment: Welcome to FrenchLanguage. Sorry but this google translation is incorrect.

Comment: I lived in bruxelles for a few years, would guess at 'ayant l'Anglais comme' - non ? thoughts ?

Comment: Yes it would be a correct then ! Trust yourself more next time :)

Comment: Why did you replace correct parts of the google translation with incorrect ones: (*la première* → **le première*) and (*l'anglais* → **l'Anglais*)?

Comment: neither sentence is correct